# "Cannot create a file when that file already exists" in Windows Terminal when opening WSL2?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having trouble running Ubuntu for WSL2 in my Windows Terminal as a regular user.

Instead of getting a bash prompt I get the following, and I think it's because I have more than one Ubuntu Distro with the same name, see below:

**Windows Version:**
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1586]

**WSL Version:** 0.0.0.0

**Are you using WSL1 or WSL2:** WSL2

**Kernel Version:** Linux version 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (oe-user@oe-host) (x86_64-msft-linux-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34.0.20200220) #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Open Windows Terminal as a non-admin account.
2. Click the down arrow tab at the top and select Ubuntu.
3. A new tab appears with the follow error message:

   Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

   [process exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)]
   You can now close this terminal with Ctrl+D, or press Enter to restart.

I think the issue has to do with the fact that there are two Ubuntu Distros named Ubuntu but that have a different GUID/UUID in the registry:

```
wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Running         2
  Ubuntu    Stopped         2
```

```
PS C:\Users\me-user> reg query hkcu\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\lxss

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\lxss
    DefaultVersion    REG_DWORD    0x2
    DefaultDistribution    REG_SZ    {c329c2ee-fd20-4986-873a-351737eaf399}

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\lxss\AppxInstallerCache
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\lxss\{97307d71-8998-42a4-9600-ff372b6ec1ee}
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\lxss\{c329c2ee-fd20-4986-873a-351737eaf399}
```

If you'll notice the 1st one has values, but the 2nd one does not:

**First one:**

```
PS C:\Users\me-user> reg query "hkcu\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\lxss\{97307d71-8998-42a4-9600-ff372b6ec1ee}" /v DistributionName

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\lxss\{97307d71-8998-42a4-9600-ff372b6ec1ee}
    DistributionName    REG_SZ    Ubuntu

PS C:\Users\me-user> reg query "hkcu\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\lxss\{97307d71-8998-42a4-9600-ff372b6ec1ee}"

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\lxss\{97307d71-8998-42a4-9600-ff372b6ec1ee}
    State    REG_DWORD    0x1
    DistributionName    REG_SZ    Ubuntu
    Version    REG_DWORD    0x2
    BasePath    REG_SZ    C:\Users\me-user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState
    Flags    REG_DWORD    0xf
    DefaultUid    REG_DWORD    0x0
    PackageFamilyName    REG_SZ    CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc
```

**2nd One**

```
PS C:\Users\me-user> reg query "hkcu\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\lxss\{c329c2ee-fd20-4986-873a-351737eaf399}" /v DistributionName

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\lxss\{c329c2ee-fd20-4986-873a-351737eaf399}
    DistributionName    REG_SZ    Ubuntu
```

(No other keys / values)

I noticed that the default wsl is set to the 2nd one `c329c2ee-fd20-4986-873a-351737eaf399`:

`DefaultDistribution    REG_SZ    {c329c2ee-fd20-4986-873a-351737eaf399}`

Is it safe to change the Default Distribution to "the 1st One" `{97307d71-8998-42a4-9600-ff372b6ec1ee}` so that I no longer see the error message when trying to open it in Window Terminal?

**Also see:** https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7998

```
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

[process exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)]
You can now close this terminal with Ctrl+D, or press Enter to restart.
```

Comment: Not sure about the different default distributions but following your link, it looks like they provided a solution. Did you try this? What looks promising is [this procedure that deletes the HNS file](https://juniper.github.io/contrail-windows-docs/Known_issues/HNS_error_bestiary/#level-beta-decontamination-procedure).

Comment: @mchid I tried turning off the service, and went to see if I could delete the nhs file, but the file isn't there, and it's not there after you start the service again either.